# Почему Нечто и Нечего - два разных слова?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, морфология

Как так вышло, что слова НЕЧТО и НЕЧЕГО не являются формами одной лексемы? С морфологической точки зрения не - приставка, что - местоимение, а чего - форма родительного падежа местоимения что. Так почему начальной формой слова "Нечему" является слово "нечего", а не "нечто", а начальной формой слова "нечего" не является слово "нечто"?

Comment: *а начальной формой слова "нечего" является слово "нечто"* - кстати, вот этот последний кусок совершенно непонятен. "Нечего" и есть сама для себя начальная форма.

Comment: Извините, описка. Имела в виду "не является", конечно же.

Comment: Так вы можете править свой текст.

Answer (score 2):

Исторически "нечто" и "нечего" как раз являются формами одного слова. Можно легко проследить, что "нечто"  не имеет форм косвенных падежей (кроме винительного, просторечные "нечта, нечту, нечтом" - вторичны),  а "нечего" имеет все, кроме именительного.

А вот как получилось... На все воля Божья, как говорится, указать прямую и однозначную причину такого явления вряд ли возможно.  Видимо, дело в том, что "нечто" в значении *"нечего" в именительном*  превратилось в "ничто" (тоже необычный факт, но объяснимый грамматикой, предлагающей регулярно заменять вторую отрицательную частицу НЕ на усилительную НИ). А форма "нечто", оставшись "без работы", была нагружена нынешним значением. Зачем и почему - эти вопросы формального ответа не имеют. Так уж сложилось.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в лексическом значении местоимений не позволяет поместить их в одну парадигму. Нечто предполагает наличие, а нечего -  отсутствие.

Comment: Да, вроде, никто и не возражает против этого. Интересуются, как могло такое случиться, что регулярная форма И.п. оказалась принадлежащей другому слову, а в качестве замены (частичной) появилось "ничто", тоже из другой парадигмы.

Answer (score -1):

**Вопрос**: Как так вышло, что слова НЕЧТО и НЕЧЕГО не являются формами одной лексемы?

**Ответ:**  НЕЧТО и НЕЧЕГО являются формами одной лексемы, они  входят в полную парадигму местоименного наречия НЕЧТО , состоящую из 6 падежных форм, но этот ряд делится на две части **по значению этих форм:** НЕЧТО (И.п. и В.п.) имеет неопределенное значение, а НЕЧЕГО, НЕЧЕМУ, НЕЧЕМ, НЕ О ЧЕМ - отрицательное значение.

**Пояснение**

**1) Со  значением отрицания** ( предмета) используются  4 формы косвенных падежей: нечего, нечему, нечем, не о чем.

2) Форма «нечто» (В.п.)  **не входит в этот ряд, так как при отрицании В.п. должен заменяться Р.п.** Форма «нечто»  выражает не отрицание, а значение неопределенности,  указывая на неопределенный, но при этом реальный  предмет.**  Это несклоняемое  неопределенное местоимение используется  в форме В.п. или И.п., являясь подлежащим или прямым дополнением, но иногда используются и другие падежи, например:

Начинается нечто интересное.

Мне предстоит играть нечто совершенно не похожее на то, что я играла раньше.

С точки зрения последовательного материализма этим «нечто» может быть только другой материальный объект.

Comment: Какое все это имеет отношение к вопросу? Вопрос был "Так **почему** начальной формой... ". Понятно, что такие вопросы очень редко имеют однозначный ответ, но городить набор банальных сведений, ответом даже близко не являющихся,  - это не дело в любом случае.

Comment: "...городить набор банальных сведений": ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ НЕГАТИВНОЙ ОЦЕНОЧНОЙ ЛЕКСИКИ  (НОЛ) НА ФОРУМЕ ЗАПРЕЩЕНО.

Comment: Sergey, с этим - чат.